# Data structure for storing entities in game

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, 2d, complexity-theory

I have a tiled map which is made of chunks and each chunk is a rectangle of tiles. Now I want to add entities to this(each entity stand on a specific tile), and every loop all the entities should call their `update()` function, so I wanted to ask for a suggestion: what data structure should I use for saving their locations?

I don't know yet what kind of methods I'll have, but I'll probably need a method that gets all the entities from a specific area(maybe a point) for drawing for example. This is a critic question because there maybe a huge map like 100x100 chunks where each chunk is 30x20 tiles so it will be 3000x2000 tiles, and lots of entities for example 1000, so if I'll save it in a list it will be very slow to search for an entities `O(n)` and if every entities make a search it will take `O(n^2)`.

Right now I have a couple of solutions but they are all problematic:

**kd-tree**(for 2d) - since each loop all the entities can change their locations, the complexity of updating them will be the same as rebuilding the whole tree each loop `O(nlogn)`.

**each chunk will save the entities that belong to it** - my best solution so far, easy updating, but the complexity is higher then in the kd-tree.

So does anybody have a suggestion for this problem?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evils"

Comment: you mention that all entities can move, but is that likely in practice? also, is there any specific reason that you can't store the relevant information twice - as in, each tile would know what is on it and each entity would separately remember which tile it is on.

Comment: Depends on your constraints, how you'll use it, and what you want to optimize. Does it have to be fast? Does it have to use memory efficiently? Or does it just have to be simple and readable? You should think about the methods before choosing a data structure.

Comment: @harold - that's an idea.. but a little too heavy, there can be more then one entity on a tile, so I'll have to change a tile from int to int and a list of entities, and the complexity of the area search will still be expensive O(area.x * area.y)... the amount of tiles is lots more then entities so it's useless for each tile to save what's on it.. it will be like null, null, null,..., null, ENTITY, null, null,...

Comment: @Vlad: I see, so your map is truly gigantic. I was thinking, well 3kx2k is not so bad, you could easily get away with 64bytes per tile at those sizes - on a desktop anyway, maybe not if this is for a smartphone or such. Anyway, something I have used is dividing the tiles into blocks of 8x8 and then letting the entire block be `null` if there's nothing in it. Would that be small enough? You have chunks already, but they're kind of big for this to work.

Comment: @harold: you are missing something.. each tile is just 1byte = char, it's just a tileID now chunk has char tiles[w][h]. my question is about the speed, there is no problem with the space.

Comment: @Vlad: then why is there a problem? If you make each tile say 5 bytes (that 1 byte + entityID) and every entity contains it's position, then everything is O(1) right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary that maps tile (position) towards a list of all entities on that tile. All entities should have a position property and an event notifying when it changes, so that the dictionary can be updated at each movement.

(There should be no list for the tiles without entities. The list should be created when an entitiy moves to that position, and removed when the last entity leaves the position.)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a crude suggestion, and I'm sure it can be improved, but here's a thought:

First, store your positions in such a way that you can access them in constant time given a specific object.  For instance, if you want to access them directly through your entities, you can store the position structs in a list/vector and give each entity a pointer/reference to its position.

Second, store an entity pointer/reference or GUID in the same struct as the entity position, so you can identify an entity based on a position object.  (There is probably a better way I'm not thinking of right now though.)

Third, utilize some of the principles of sweep and prune/sort and sweep (common in 3D games):  Keep two sorted position lists/vectors, one sorted in the x direction and the other sorted in the y direction.  One can hold the actual position objects, and the other can hold pointers/references.  These lists can take advantage of temporal coherence, so the cost of keeping them sorted shouldn't be too high, unless there's a lot of fast and chaotic movement.

An advantage of this setup is that it's really easy to figure out where every object is relative to each other.  Want to know how many objects are within 10 squares of Billy the Elf in either direction?  Check Billy's position and iterate forward/backward through both lists until you reach an entity more than 10 squares away in each direction.

If you're interested in the concept, look up sort and sweep (also known as sweep and prune).  You'd only be using the first half of the algorithm, but it's used for broad-phase collision detection in practically every major 3D physics engine, so you know that it has to be fast in general. ;)  There's a lot of information floating around about it, so you'll probably find much more sophisticated implementation ideas floating around too.  (For instance, I don't like the indirection involved in storing a sorted list of pointers/references to position structs; working with the actual structs is more cache-efficient, but then you need to update the position in two places if you want to exploit temporal coherency with persistent arrays.  Someone else may have thought of a more clever design that's escaping me right now.)

**EDIT:  I'd comment on Erik H's idea, but my rep isn't high enough.  I just wanted to say that his idea sounds very well suited to your game, especially if you will have a lot of entities tightly packed on the same tile or in a small neighborhood.  If I were you, I'd probably try it before the sweep and prune idea.  However, it should be accompanied with a well-planned memory management strategy:**  If you have a dictionary of tile locations that naively map to vectors of entities, you're going to have a lot of memory being allocated and freed when entities move from one tile to another.  Instead, you'll want to implement his idea as something more like a dictionary/linked list combo:

The dictionary keys would be tile positions, and the dictionary would return a single pointer to a linked list node.  This node would be part of a linked list of all entities on the same tile.  Whenever an entity moves from one tile to another, it will be removed from its current linked list and added to the new one.  If an entity moves to an empty tile, it will be in a linked list all on its own, and it should be added to the dictionary.  When the last entity moves from a tile, the entry for that tile should be removed from the dictionary.  This will allow you to move around entities without continual dynamic allocation/deallocation, since you're just updating pointers (and the dictionary will probably be pretty memory efficient).

Note that you don't have to store full-blown entities in the linked lists, either; you can easily create your linked list out of lightweight objects (containing a pointer or GUID to the actual entity).